# How to use phalcon query builder without ORM

Tags: php, orm, datamapper, phalcon, query-builder

Hello everyone I'm trying to use phalcon without ORM. I want to separate business logic and data access with DataMapper pattern and I can't find how I can build queries without raw SQL, but using original phalcon queryBuilder.

Is there any chance to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php

//Getting a whole set
$robots = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from('Robots')
    ->join('RobotsParts')
    ->orderBy('Robots.name')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();

//Getting the first row
$robots = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from('Robots')
    ->join('RobotsParts')
    ->orderBy('Robots.name')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult();
```

From Phalcon docs: [Phalcon Query Language (PHQL)](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#creating-queries-using-the-query-builder)

Comment: Yep, but in that case you need model Robots extended from Phalcon ORM, but my models are simple and I don't want to link them with db tables. Maybe there is no way, besides raw SQL.

Comment: You might be able to create you own builder. You would have to override the getPhql() method and add a table() method. Then you would have to set the hydration mode to array.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it
I'm using phalcon with doctrine DBAL
it's working great for me

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 ways solve it if i'm not mistaken.

Solution 1#

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder; 

$result = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
  ->columns("table1.f1, table1.f2,table2.f3,table2.f4")
  ->From('table1')
  ->innerjoin('table2', 'table1.matchfield = table2.matchfield')
  ->where("table1.fieldname = '$value' ")
  ->getQuery()
  ->execute();
```

Solution 2#

```
 $res = $this->db->execute("UPDATE Tablename SET field1= ?,field2=?,field3=? WHERE id = ?",array($field1,$field2,$field3,$id));
```